# classic asp verify the server result

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to check or unchecked the check-boxes depends upon the data results that comes from server. But I cannot use below code correctly where I am doing wrong?

```
<%
Dim AFTER_SAVE, IN_VIEW, Y
Dim SQL, Data
SQL = " SELECT code, name, value FROM mytable WHERE code = '" & User & "'" 
Data = Data(SQL)
%>  
    <%If IsArray(Data) Then%>
         <%If ((Data(1,0) = "AFTER_SAVE") AND (Data(2,0) = "Y")) Then %>      
                document.getElementById("chkSave").checked == true;                      
         <%End If%>
         <% If ((Data(1,0) = "IN_VIEW") AND (Data(2,0) = "Y")) Then %>       
                document.getElementById("chkVIEW").checked == true;  
         <%End If%>
  <%End If%>
```

Comment: What output is rendered to the browser? Knowing this would help narrow down where the error is occurring

Comment: well I dont see any error that rendered to the browser. It just not working.

Comment: Do you see either of the pieces of javascript within the ASP IF statements in the rendered HTML? i.e. "document.getElementById("chkSave").checked == true;" or "document.getElementById("chkVIEW").checked == true;"

Comment: Also, are the pieces of Javascript enclosed in a <script> tag?

Comment: @user3138076: What is `Data = Data(SQL)`?  Does this not cause an error?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You need AJAX here. It's easy to learn and use these days, especially if you choose jQuery or similar JS library. Good luck!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: why do you think AJAX is needed? Both the checkboxes and their checked state come from the server. AJAX is for seamlessly incorporating *user* (i.e. client-side) input with server data.

Comment: @Martha as far as I understand, the OP here want to get data from the server when doing some client side event then based on that tick or untick the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to combine server-side code with client-side code in a very strange way. Sometimes, it's necessary to do that (i.e. use server-side VBScript to write client-side Javascript), but if I'm understanding your intent correctly, it's not needed here.

Basically, if this is actually a classic ASP page, then somewhere on that page you're generating the checkboxes in question. So all you need to do is put your database call somewhere before that, and then when you generate the checkboxes, you can output a `checked='checked'`, or not, depending.

<sub>Note that I have no clue what `Data = Data(SQL)` is supposed to mean. There's no way for it to be valid VBScript code - parentheses are for arrays, but a string is not a valid array index, and then to assign it to itself like that? Anyway, I'm ignoring that part.</sub>

```vbs
<html>
<head>
<%
Dim AFTER_SAVE, IN_VIEW
Dim SQL, RS, Conn
Dim User
'...blah blah blah, give a value to User, set up your DB connection, etc. etc....

SQL = "SELECT code, name, [value] FROM mytable WHERE code = '" & User & "'"
'- ("value" is a reserved keyword in SQL, hence the brackets)
Set RS = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open SQL, Conn, 1, 2 '- this is rather handwavy and unlikely to actually
'- work as-is; use the options and connection methods that make sense for you
Do Until RS.EOF
    '- I have no idea how your data is set up; this may make no sense.
    '- The idea is, read the checkbox states from your database, and 
    '- stick them in variables for later reference.
    Select Case RS("name")
        Case "AFTER_SAVE" AFTER_SAVE = RS("value")
        Case "IN_VIEW"   IN_VIEW = RS("value")
    End Select
    RS.Movenext
Loop
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
%>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="myformhandler.asp">
<!-- form fields and stuff -->
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSave" id="chkSave" <%
If AFTER_SAVE = "Y" Then Response.Write "checked='checked'"
%> value="Y"><label for="chkSave">After save</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkView" id="chkView" <%
If IN_VIEW = "Y" Then Response.Write "checked='checked'"
%> value="Y"><label for="chkView">In view</label>
<!-- more form stuff -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```