# Classic asp server-side script result for check box checked or not?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am using classic Asp and trying to make my checked box named '**chkuser**' checked if below sql statement is correct. ***invData() does all the connections etc.*** in below code

```
<% 

Dim mySQL, myData                   




If IsArray(myData) Then
    'check box is checked.
End If

%>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your previous one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907681/classic-asp-verify-the-server-result?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
' your database code
Dim checked

If IsArray(myData) Then
  checked = "checked"
End If
&>
```

Then code your checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkuser"  <%= checked %> />
```

Comment: That's not a good way of setting the "checked" state of a checkbox. Better to do it [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `<% If IsArray(myData) Then : chkuser.Checked = True : End If %>`.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers - Your link is to a page about an asp.net control.  Does what you suggest also work with Classic ASP?